# Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in

Tags: php, mysqli, centos

I execute this on my centos/WHM server :

```php
<?
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
?>
```

Result is: `We don't have mysqli!!!`

My problem is that:

> Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/photosdr/public_html/includes/database.php on line 18

So how can I install it ? 
Thank you

Comment: My probleme is that : Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/photosdr/public_html/includes/database.php on line 18

Comment: $this->res = new mysqli( $conf[ 'dbhost' ], $conf[ 'dbuser' ], $conf[ 'dbpass' ], $conf[ 'dbname' ] );

Comment: @mgraph: If that were the problem, nothing would appear in the page (unless you viewed the page source, in which case you'd see the raw PHP code).  The problem is that the mysqli module isn't installed and/or enabled.

Comment: yes, how can i install mysqli extention , thats my question :)

Comment: If it's already there, then you might try adding `extension = php_mysqli.so` in your php.ini.  Yum should have included it with your PHP, so if it didn't, you probably don't have a prepackaged PHP...and you'll have to rebuild it with the module enabled.

Comment: Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) for instructions on enabling or installing mysqli

Comment: i added extension = php_mysqli.so to php.ini, same issue .

Comment: Sachleen, i already follow the link you give me, butt didnt work. im nor expert in centos.

Comment: @YoussefEssaaf: Does your server have WHM/CPanel installed?

Comment: cHao, yes , i have WHM/Cpanel installed. im a root.

Comment: Go in there and look around.  WHM likes to build its own PHP, and there should be a tool under "Software" labeled "EasyApache (Apache Update)".  Click that and go through the steps...along the way you'll get to pick what modules PHP gets built with.  Make sure to include mysqli.  :)

Comment: @cHao , i found easyapache, and now i have 7 steps, wait, im triyng...

Comment: It'll take a while to build...maybe as much as 30-45 minutes once you're done configuring.  So, no rush.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Try finding `extension=php_mysqli.so` in your `php.ini` and remove comment in front of it.

Comment: This is a Linux server.  Extensions have `.so` rather than `.dll` at the end.

Comment: same issue, i put php.ini but same issue

Comment: @YoussefEssaaf remember that you need to restart your webserver after making changes in `php.ini` file...

Comment: @Qmal, same issue after restart. now im working on whm to find how to add mysqli to php

Comment: have you found any solution? I'm also using GoDaddy VPS and stuck with this MySQLi extension stuff? Please share.

Comment: have you solve problem? I am fetching same problem.